# How to keep rows in the same line horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
div{
    float: left;
    width: 30.33%;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
```

See? Everything is arranged and neat. All fine. But when the height of a box getting more than others, the rows will be interwoven (disordered). See:

```css
div{
    float: left;
    width: 30.33%;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I keep rows in the same line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use FlexBox :

```css
.wrapper div {
  width: 30.33%;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 6px;
}
.wrapper{
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add additional div for every row.

**Here is an working example**

```css
.row {
  clear: both;
}

.row div {
  float: left;
  width: 30.33%;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could alternatively use `flexbox` but it is less supported than `float`. You can see which browsers are compatible [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: why floating the row? better clear float instead of having everything floated

Comment: @TemaniAfif good point, thank you (I edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add  `display: flex;` and    `flex-wrap: wrap;` to any wrapper div around your 33.3% width divs

```css
body {    
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div{
    float: left;
    width: 30.33%;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever   whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p> whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever  whatever 
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can either use a table / you can add one more property to you css with height of some fixed height. then this issue will be resolved.